# How can I separate consecutive points from overlapping points in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

I have a point shapefile with tracks of a machine. I'm looking to peel apart the overlapping point on a single track. The idea is that I'm looking at machine compaction on the soil and I have data for this at every point, but I'd like to see if with every pass of the machine, I can separate (i.e. peel back like an onion), the different machine passes to show them one at a time. I attached an image of what the points look like. In some rows, the machine only did one pass, but in others it went back and ran over it's previous tracks. Is there a tool that I can use, or a method to cluster all the points from the first pass into one shapefile, and every consecutive pass on top would be separated out? I have date/time information for each point as well.

[image]

Comment: how many passes were there total?

Comment: It varies. On some roads the machine only goes once, but on others it could be dozens.

Answer (score 1):

You can download and install an ArcGIS tool called Split By Attribute. This was authored by the USGS.  This tool will create a seperate Shapefile for each Field Value. For example, all Points with 01/01/16 date will be copied to shapefile 010116.shp, All Points with date 01/02/16 will be copied to shapefile 010216.shp.
[SplitByAttribute](http://www.umesc.usgs.gov/management/dss/split_by_attribute_tool.html)

Comment: Hmmm, that might work. The main issue I see is that the machine goes over the same area multiple times in a day, so I'd have to create a new field that could identify each track run and then use the split by attribute. I'll give it a try tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you use your date/time attributes to assign a priority or sort order attribute to each of the layers of your onion, and then either clip out the various layers into different shapefiles depending on priority, or you could use symbology to distinguish between your different layers if visualized all at once? 
Just an idea, I use it when I have multiple sales of individual properties within a given year. I get overlapping points based on my addresses, but distinguish older sales from more recent sales by assigning priorities 1-4 in a seperate field that I add to the data in editor mode. Then using symbology I can assign different colors to different values.

Comment: The main issue with that would be that I normally change the symbology because I'm looking at machine rutting (how much it displaces the soil when it moves over it), so I already have one layer of symbology. And in some cases for analysis I'd like to just remove consecutive layers and look at just the underlying ones. I could manually clip them out by layer but I have literally millions of points over two years and in some places the machine overlaps itself up to 60-100 times. A bit tedious to do by hand.